# Python Django ORM select custom DB for raw query by session variable

Tags: python, django, oracle, orm, router

Given the following raw query, inside a view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def view(request):
    result = CustomObject.objects.raw("SELECT a, b, c FROM table WHERE d = %(param)s", {
        'param': 123
    })

    ...

    return render(request, 'templates/template.html', {
        'a': 'b'
    })
```

I use a router to route the query to a DB (use case is read only).

```
class MyDBRouter(object):
    @staticmethod
    def db_for_read(model, **hints):
        if model == CustomObject:
            return 'customdb'
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def db_for_write(model, **hints):
        return None
```

I have the available databases configured:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'customdb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'xxx.yyy.zzz:1234/DB',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

During login, the User can specify which database he wants to execute the commands on. Depending on the session, I have to use different databases to connect to, therefore I have to specify manually for each request which DB it goes to.

**Question:**

- How can I access my session variables from a static method of a router?
- If using routers is not advised in this specific case, what other options do I have for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do this way

If you need to use custom database on the fly you can pass it in

```
def login(request):
    # Your logic
    request.session["db-name"] = "customdb"
    # Your logic

def query_view(request):
    db_name = request.session.get("db-name", "default")
    # execute your query with this db_name like 

    MyModel.objects.using(db_name).raw("Your query")
```

Also if you want your session key to be unique then you can use unique username also like this

```
request.session[f"{request.user.username}_{db_name}"] = "customdb"
```

And access it in other views.